# How to disable adding new tags in bootstrap tagsinput?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm going to use bootstrap tagsinput without adding new tags feature (only remove tags). How to disable adding new tags?

I'm using latest bootstrap tagsinput v0.8.0 with twitter bootstrap 3.

Here is my snippet:

```
<input id="removeonlyinput" type="text" value="Amsterdam,Berlin,Lisbon" data-role="tagsinput" />

<script>
$('#removeonlyinput').tagsinput({
      freeinput: false
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about making the input field readonly ? By this no user can type in the input text.

```
$('input[type=text]').prop("readonly", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `beforeItemAdd` event:

```
$('#removeonlyinput').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
  event.cancel = true;
});
```

Comment: this works, and you can also do the same for beforeItemRemove to make the tagit field 'read only'

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` file.

find `maxTags:,` line and make it `maxTags: 0,`

Then it won't add new tags.

In this way I achieved the functionality.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This option is documeted in official documentation and if it is set 0, it means unlimited tags number. Also, in this case (if you define maxTags as "1") you can delete tag and add new which is not acceptable for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
$( "#removeonlyinput" ).prop( "disabled", true );
```

don't mind the extra spaces.

Comment: i just found it now, while I'm trying to disable my tagsinput too.

Answer (score 0):

it's not

```
freeinput: false
```

it's

```
freeInput: false
```